# Remove all subviews except named

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiview, subview

I would like to removed all subviews of my UIViewController except two that are named `toolBarOne` and `toolBarTwo`. I am not sure where I should start. What is your suggestion? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't quite do it the way Sony suggested for a couple reasons.

1. By doing it that way, you'll be removing subviews while using that same subview array for enumeration.
2. You may also be removing the layout-related subviews, i.e. `UILayoutGuide`, that you didn't explicitly add to your view.

Instead, I recommend iterating over a separate array containing a copy of your original `self.view.subviews` array and excluding any subviews of type `UILayoutSupport`:

```
var subviews = self.view.subviews
for subview in subviews as [UIView] {
    if subview != toolBarOne && subview != toolBarTwo && !(subview is UILayoutSupport) {
        subview.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    for subView in view.subviews as [UIView] {
        if subView != toolBarOne && subView != toolBarTwo {
            subView.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
```